# Lending Club Folio secondary market listings API call not working

Tags: python, python-requests, lending-club-api

I am trying to use this Python code to access the Folio API for the secondary market listings.  Similar code worked for me in the primary Lending Club listings.  This returns an error code [500], an internal error.

```
import requests
lc_InvestorId = "1111"
lc_apikey = "xxxx"
lc_module = 'secondarymarket/listings'
url = f"https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/{lc_module}"

payload = {}

params = {'updatedSince':10000}

headers = {
    'ContentType': "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Authorization': lc_apikey,
    'X-LC-Application-Key': lc_InvestorId
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Folio Note Trading API manual (1/22/2018):

> Supported formats: CSV
>
> For the Listings GET call, you must include the
> Accept: text/csv header and exclude the Content-Type header

Changing the headers to this worked:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': "text/csv",
    'Authorization': lc_apikey,
    'X-LC-Application-Key': lc_InvestorId
    }
```